# Python Convert multiple line code to a single line code

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I wanted to convert following multiple lines of code to a single line. I have tried but i am unable to achieve final result.

Multiple line of code :-

```
for k, v in FLOW_GROUPS.items():
    if k == '':
        [pd.Series(df_by_fulfillment_flow[v].sum(axis=1), name=k)]
    else:
        [pd.Series(df_by_fulfillment_flow[v].mean(axis=1), name=k)]
```

my success so far is given below, i want to add if condition also to it :-

```
[pd.Series(df_by_fulfillment_flow[v].sum(axis=1), name=k) for k, v in FLOW_GROUPS.items()]
```

Comment: I suppose you are trying to create a list, but your base code doesn't

Comment: @PlainRavioli Yes you are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ternary loop with if else Syntax:

```
[<ifvalue> if <condition> else <elsevalue> for i in <yourdata>]
```

ternary loop with if statement only Syntax:

```
[<value> for i in <yourdata> if <condition>]
```

Although I dont know your input and desire output, but with syntax your single line code should be like:

```
[[pd.Series(df_by_fulfillment_flow[v].sum(axis=1), name=k)] if k == '' else [pd.Series(df_by_fulfillment_flow[v].mean(axis=1), name=k)] for k, v in FLOW_GROUPS.items()]
```

Comment: You are close to solution which worked for me. Solution which worked for me is ```[pd.Series(df_by_fulfillment_flow[v].sum(axis=1), name=k) if k == 'operational_result' else pd.Series(df_by_fulfillment_flow[v].mean(axis=1), name=k) for k, v in FLOW_GROUPS.items()] ```